# Анимация при зажатии

Tags: android

Как сделать при нажатии такую анимацию, чтобы типо серый круг увеличивался. (Не знаю как назвать это, все на скриншотах)[image: кнопка]

Comment: Со скриншотом понятнее не стало

Comment: уточните вопрос или укажите пример, а очень похоже на view.animate().scaleX(float).scaleY(float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас понял, то вам нужен *Ripple Effect*

Добавляете

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Если ваша View уже имеет какой-то `background` то:

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Решение через `foreground` работает только для API >= 23

Если вам нужно что-то более кастомное, то можно написать что-то похожее на это, с вашими настройками

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius_large" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:type="linear" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius_large" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

И задать в параметре `background` вашей `View`

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/button_background" />
```

Comment: Да вы мой спаситель, благодарю! Первое помогло :)

Comment: Ам... А еще один вопросик. А как это сделать круглым? У меня квадрат почему-то в анимации

Comment: `attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` для выхода за пределы `view`

Comment: @vlad-orlinskas ничего не изменилось, также остался квадрат при нажатии

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941753/how-to-make-a-circular-ripple-on-a-button-when-its-being-clicked Посмотрите, это может вам помочь